# Are mixin parenthesis optional when nested?

Tags: less, less-mixins

Consider the following:

```
.flashing {

    .flashKeyFrames(fade-in;{
        0%, 100% {opacity: 1;}
        50% {opacity: 0;}
        });

    .flashing(fade-in linear infinite alternate; 1s)

}

.flashKeyFrames(@name; @arguments) {
    @-moz-keyframes @name { @arguments(); }
    @-webkit-keyframes @name { @arguments(); }
    @keyframes @name { @arguments(); }
}

.flashing(@arguments, @duration) {
    -webkit-animation: @arguments;
    -moz-animation: @arguments;
    animation: @arguments;

    -webkit-animation-duration: @duration;
    -moz-animation-duration: @duration;
    animation-duration: @duration;
}
```

What are the parenthesis necessarily after `@arguments`? I thought parenthesis were optional when used as mixins? So I'm assuming `@arguments` isn't being defined as a mixin, but then what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the `@arguments` used in the `.flashKeyFrames` is ***not a mixin***. It ***is an argument*** that is passed to the mixin. The value set that is set to this argument is a [***detached ruleset***](http://lesscss.org/features/#detached-rulesets-feature) and for a detached ruleset call to work, the parentheses `()` at the end is mandatory. Below is the extract from the Less website:

> Parentheses after a ***detached ruleset call are mandatory***. The call `@detached-ruleset;` would NOT work.

Parentheses are not optional only when calling a mixin and not a ruleset.